# than doing, do, or to do?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is more appropriate?

> It is more important to maintain *success* than **achieving**/**to achieve**/**achieve** *success*.
>
> It is more important to maintain than **achieving**/**to achieve**/**achieve** *success*.
>
> It is more important to maintain *success* than **achieving**/**to achieve**/**achieve** *it*.

Answer (score 1):

Any of the forms of the sentence that your wrote woudld be correct. In order to maintain the parallelism, it is best to use "to achieve," regardless of which form you use.

As for which sounds the most natural, it would probably be the third:

> It is more important to maintain success than to achieve it.

This is because we already mention "success" in the sentence, so it is more concise to just use "it" the second time around, rather than repeating the word.

The second form also uses "success" only once, but the structure is such that you don't know what the sentence is talking about until the end, so it is harder to parse and therefore less preferable.

Answer (score 0):

The statement should be said like this:

> It is more important to maintain success, than it is to achieve success.

Comment: The comma is not right. :)